# How to get image file from public folder as a response in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

These are different ways I have tried in my controller to get image as response.

My images resides in `public folder/img`.

```
switch ($document->ext) {

    case 'doc':
        $img = File::get(url('/img/doc.png'));
        break;

    case 'docx':
        $img = File::get(asset('/img/docx.jpg'));
        break;

    case 'pdf':
        $img = File::get(public_path('/img/pdf.png'));
        break;

    case 'ppt':
        $img = File::get(url(public_path('/img/ppt.png')));
        break;

    default:
}
return new Response($img, 200);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess it is a better way in case we change the public_path

```
        case 'doc':
        return response()->file(public_path('img/doc.png'));
        exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

add public before you folder name

```
$img = File::get(url('public/img/doc.png'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to **download** a file from **public folder** with the option to **setting a name**

```
public function downloadSample(){
        return Response::download(public_path("folder/my_file.xlsx"),
                     'your_file_name_when_downloaded.xslx');
    }
```